# Why does defining a variable outside a function produce different behavior than when defined inside a function? Scoping related?

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and in this program I encountered some strange behavior that I would like to understand.

Some context: `resetButton` is a button to reset the elements in `boxes` to their initial state. As part of this process, I clone all the elements in `boxes` to remove their event listeners. Next, I would like to re-add the event listeners to the new elements. This is where the problem arises.

In the first code snippet, `boxes` is defined outside the `initializeBoxes` and the `addEventListener` for `resetButton` and it seems like I am unable to add event listeners to the elements in `boxes`

In the second code snippet, `boxes` is defined inside each function and this code works fine. It looks like the event listeners are cleared and re-added when `initalizeBoxes` is called.

I think this has to do with scope, however I thought that `initalizeBoxes`'s closure would capture `boxes` from outside the function. This is where I can't understand what is really happening. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

```
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    
let resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');
resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    boxes.forEach((box) => {
        box.replaceWith(box.cloneNode(true));
    });
    initalizeBoxes();
});

function initalizeBoxes() {
    boxes.forEach((box) => {
        box.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // do stuff
```

```
let resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');
resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    boxes.forEach((box) => {
        box.replaceWith(box.cloneNode(true));
    });
    initalizeBoxes();
});

function initalizeBoxes() {
    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    boxes.forEach((box) => {
        box.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet, the `boxes` variable refers to the collection of elements matching `.box` that existed at the moment that line was run - `let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');` - so, those elements *when the page was loaded*. The first time the button is clicked, `boxes.forEach((box) => { box.replaceWith` may properly iterate over all those elements. But then if you click the button again sometime, all elements in the `boxes` variable refer to elements no longer in the document, so calling `.replaceWith` on them doesn't affect anything in the current DOM.

In contrast, if you select the boxes inside the button's click listener, you'll be selecting all boxes that exist in the DOM at that point, so you'll be guaranteed to have an up-to-date collection to iterate over and replace.